# CSS Width:100% not working in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, width, figure

I'm trying to build gallery-section with `captions` based on `figure` and `figcaptions`.
It must be responsive and work with different `height`/`width along with its`figcaption`.

Everything works well in `firefox`, but unfortunately `chrome` doesn't follow the 100% `width` in `CSS` which is significant.

```
figure {
  margin: 6px;
  color: #333;
  /*display: table;
  float: left;*/
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
   box-sizing: border-box ;

}
figure figcaption {
  background: #E3E3E3;
  padding: 10px 12px 12px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
  box-sizing: border-box ;
}
```

Here's my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tm4tjp4c/12)

Please help.

Comment: width:100% is not working with display:table-caption. Make display:block or table.

Comment: @locateganesh - but gallery should be aligned inline...

Comment: then either you can give with in pixels or write jquery code like http://jsfiddle.net/tm4tjp4c/14/

Comment: Add 
figure figcaption {display:block}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display:inline-table`  for **figure** and remove `width:100%` from **figcaption**.

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nsfjk5mm/1/) working in both **Chrome** and **Firefox**.

```
figure {
    margin: 6px;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-table;  /*changed to inline-table*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
     box-sizing: border-box ;
}

figure figcaption {
    background: #E3E3E3;
    padding: 10px 12px 12px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    /*  width:100%;   */
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
    box-sizing: border-box ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change width: 100% to width: 300px; it will support both.

Comment: It must be responsible and images can have different size

Answer (score 0):

Please see below fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tm4tjp4c/13/
works in both chrome and Mozilla

I have added `display:table`  to figure and removed `width:100%` from figure caption

```
figure {
    margin: 6px;
    color: #333;
    /*display: table;
    float: left;*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
    box-sizing: border-box ;
    display:table;
 }
figure figcaption {
    background: #E3E3E3;
    padding: 10px 12px 12px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
    box-sizing: border-box ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work well, except you have to insert `<div></div>` and have some kind of fixed width or max-width.

```css
figure {
 margin: 6px;
    max-width: 300px;
 color: #333;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
    box-sizing: border-box ;

}
figure figcaption {
    background: #E3E3E3;
    padding: 10px 12px 12px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
 font-size: 13px;
 width: 100%;
 display: table-caption;
 caption-side: bottom;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
 box-sizing: border-box ;
}
figure div{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <div>
    <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d800/img/sample01/img_01.png" >
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    </figcaption>
        </div>
</figure>
<figure>
    <div>
    <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d800/img/sample01/img_01.png" >
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmofgdgdfgdfgfdgd tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore maasdsa dsa ds ad sad as dsa dsa dsa ds das d asd sa da  gna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    </figcaption>
        </div>
</figure>
    <figure>
        <div>
    <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d800/img/sample01/img_01.png" >
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquafgfdg. Ut enim ad minimrfgdfg gf fdg f g fd gfd g  veniam, quifdgfds nostrud fdgfdgexercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    </figcaption>
        </div>
</figure>
        <figure>
            <div>
    <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d800/img/sample01/img_01.png" >
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim as das dasd a re efsfsdghfsd fhsd fsdf hds fhds fhsd fhsd fhsdk fhsd fhdskj fhsdk fhsdkfh hsdf kdshfsdh fshdsfh ksdhf sdfdd minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    </figcaption>
        </div>
</figure>
<figure>
    <div>
    <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d800/img/sample01/img_01.png" >
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmofgdgdfgdfgfdgd tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore maasdsa dsa ds ad sad as dsa dsa dsa ds das d asd sa da  gna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    </figcaption>
</figure>
    <figure>
        <div>
    <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d800/img/sample01/img_01.png" >
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquafgfdg. Ut enim ad minimrfgdfg gf fdg f g fd gfd g  veniam, quifdgfds nostrud fdgfdgexercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    </figcaption>
        </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Almost - images should be aligned to the top.

Comment: Solution is good but it would be better without extra html code

Answer (score -1):

Put each figure-element into figurebox-element.
Set figurebox.display to inline-block (and valign top)
Set figure.display to floating-left table. (After Your comment)

```
figurebox {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

figure {
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

<figurebox>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d800/img/sample01/img_01.png" >
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex asl;lf kasdfkla ;lsl sf;la dsfhasfqw qw eiiwyq uoqw ruiq qeiwory qwoeroqewr uiqw ryqwerqew rqew rqwe rqewr qwer qwe qew r qwer qwe rqwer qwer 
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</figurebox>
```

see updated example http://jsfiddle.net/t28gjzpv/1/

Comment: Please show a reference for this `figurebox` element...I'm not sure it exists.